# How to match from the end of the string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Im not good in regular exp, i want to match a string begginning from the end of the other string.

```
var keyword = new Array();
keyword[0] = " void main";

var pool1 = "abdodfo void main";
var pool2 = "abdodfo void main a";
var pool3 = "abdodfo void main ab void mai";
```

What will be the **right regex in the control struct to satisfy the ff:**

*should match

```
if(pool1.match(keyword[0]))
```

*should NOT match

```
if(pool2.match(keyword[0]))

if(pool3.match(keyword[0]))
```

I made this code simpler, i will use this for **syntax checking error** of my c++ IDE project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$` to denote end of the input string:

```
/ void main$/
```

---

```
var pattern = / void main$/;

var pool1 = "abdodfo void main";
var pool2 = "abdodfo void main a";
var pool3 = "abdodfo void main ab void mai";

console.log(pattern.test(pool1)); // => true
console.log(pattern.test(pool2)); // => false
console.log(pattern.test(pool3)); // => false
```

Comment: how to modify the pattern wherein it should match even if there is a ton of whitespaces between 'void' and 'main'?

Comment: @fireflieslive, Use `/\s+void\s+main$/` then. `\s+` match 1 or more spaces.

Comment: this wont match for 'void main'. Can u modify to be true if there is a whitespace or NONE before 'void main'?

Comment: @fireflieslive, Try `/\s*void\s+main$/`.

Answer (score 1):

## Using regular expressions

The `$` symbol denotes the end of a string:

```
var test = " void main";

var matches = test.match(/main$/); // returns an array of matches, in this case ["main"]

if (matches.length > 0) {
  // do stuff
}
```

## Using `slice()`

In this particular case, you could also use the `slice()` function, which might be simpler:

```
var test = " void main";

if (test.slice(-4) === "main") {
  // do stuff
};
```

A [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fslice) to [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org)'s documentation on `slice()`.